# Which directory rm removed?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I need to remove all files in public_html/

I login as user name `admin`

I perform:

```
cd /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html/
rm /*
```

I thought it will remove all files in `public_html/` but linux ask me to remove directories:

```
/backup /bin /boot /data /dev /etc /home /initrd.img /initrd.img.old /lib /lib64 /lost+found /media /mnt /opt /proc /root /run /sbin /srv /swapfile /sys /tmp /usr /var /vmlinuz /vmlinuz.old
```

Which directory I have removed?

## Thanks

edit
Thanks @Aguardientico I have removed `/` directory. Since I perform `rm /*` using `user` instead of `root`, then I haven't removed anything, right?

Thanks

Comment: `/` means root directory, you should try: `rm ./*` or just `rm *`

Comment: Thanks @Aguardientico I have removed `/` directory. Since I perform `rm /*` using `user` instead of `root`, then I haven't removed anything, right?

Comment: You are right, probably you could not remove anything.

Comment: Thanks @Aguardientico I hope I haven't removed anyhing ...

Comment: Only as a comment, as you used only `rm /*` and not used `-r` option (recursive) and/or `-f` (force) you probably only affected the entries in the root directory (all of them probably belong to `root` user) so you have not removed any file.  If you used `rm -rf /*` then you probably erased all the files belonging to the user executing the command.

Answer (score 0):

one way to remove files is the command rmdir to remove the directory of the public_html which will remove all the files

```
cd /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/
rmdir public_html
```

so you go to the directory where the file is and then you delete it and it will remove all files in that directory and the folder itself, then if you need the folder you can just remake it.
here is a link http://www.computerhope.com/unix/urmdir.htm

Answer (score 0):

It all depends if you are the Admin user on the server. But typically `public_html/` is located in `/var/www/`

Answer (score 0):

```
$ cd /home/admin/web/mydomain.com/public_html/
$ ls
$ rm *
```

Comment: Although the code is appreciated, it should always have an accompanying explanation. This doesn't have to be long but it is expected.